# Quantum corrections for protons in hydrogen bonds (even at high temperatures?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, semiclassical

Consider a proton transfer reaction in some biomolecule at approximately room temperature. There are hundreds of examples of such reactions in enzymes, DNA, clusters of waters,... The energetic landscape or free energy profile in terms of a reaction coordinate (usually the distance of the proton to some heavy atom) is calculated always assuming the proton is a classical particle (although of course the calculation of the electronic structure is done with DFT or some quantum chemistry method). Free energy methods such as WHAM or Thermodynamic Integration are based on classical statistical physics. A natural question is to wonder what corrections would introduce treating the proton as a quantum particle, and for that it is possible to use Wigner's [quantum corrections to thermodynamic equilibrium](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.40.749).
To simplify, I am considering just the problem of a one-dimensional particle. This is a reasonable starting model for a proton in a hydrogen bond. Let's say that the potential energy the proton "feels" is $V(x)$, with $x$ labeling the reaction coordinate along the hydrogen bond. The classical probability density (up to a normalizing constant) in the canonical ensemble is just Boltzmann's function, $e^{-\beta V(x)}.$ Wigner's correction to second order (check equation 28 of the paper linked above) in this case tells us that the corrected probability density (again, up to a normalizing constant) is:
 $$P(x) = e^{-\beta V(x)} \left( 1-\dfrac{\hbar^2 \beta^2}{12m} \dfrac{d^2 V(x)}{d x^2}+\dfrac{\hbar^2 \beta^3}{24m} \left(\dfrac{d V(x)}{d x} \right)^2 \right).$$

Now, what has me worried about this expression is that that correction term seems to be extremely large!
My estimations are as follows. The orders of magnitude of the constants in their correspondent units in SI units are $\hbar \sim 10^{-34}, \ k_b \sim 10^{-23}$ and $m \sim 10^{-27}.$ The energies ($V$) would be of the order of $eV$, so $V \sim 10^{-18},$ while the distance, $x,$ should be of the order of ångström, so $x \sim 10^{-10}.$  This all means that, even assuming a large of temperature $T \sim 10^2,$ the correction terms are very large:
$$\dfrac{\hbar^2 \beta^2}{12m} \dfrac{d^2 V(x)}{d x^2} \sim \dfrac{10^{-68}}{10^{-27}10^{-46}10^2}\left( \dfrac{10^{-18}}{10^{-10}10^{-10}} \right) \sim 10^3,$$
$$\dfrac{\hbar^2 \beta^3}{24m} \left(\dfrac{d V(x)}{d x} \right)^2 \sim \dfrac{10^{-68}}{10^{-27}10^{-69} 10^2} \left( \dfrac{10^{-18}}{10^{-10}} \right)^2\sim 10^8.$$

Obviously something must be very wrong in all this reasoning! According to these estimations, the quantum corrections for a proton in a hydrogen bond at room temperatures would be incredibly large, so that all the typical calculations one encounters for energetic landscapes or free energy profiles would be wrong. Experiments of course show good agreement with such energetic profiles in many known cases, so these quantum corrections cannot be correct. However, I have been struggling with this for a while now and I am uncapable of seeing what is wrong with my argument.

Comment: The first thing I'd guess is that you are wrong about the energy and distance scales in the problem? $eV$ and angstrom are a typical scales for atomic physics, I'd expect a lower energy scale and longer length scale for molecular physics. I'd be surprised if this alone contributed more than a factor of 100 though.

Comment: Just to record this for later: using $0.2eV$ as a typical hydrogen bond energy (~20kJ/mol) and 2angstrom for the bond length (this is apparently typical of water) along with reasonably accurate values of the other constants I get $0.23$ for the first estimate and $2.7$ for the second. In particular, I think the values you have written down you have actually substituted $T=10K$ not $T=100K$ and also the factors of $12,24$ are not really small enough to ignore.